# Inno Setup built-in control names

Tags: inno-setup

I frequently find that I need the names of built-in controls e.g. `WizardForm.StatusLabel`. Is there a definitive reference to all the built-in control names somewhere, and if not, how do you go about finding these? As a worked example, how would I find the name of the control that shows the filename that is being extracted on the `WizardForm.InstallingPage` i.e. the label underneath the `WizardForm.StatusLabel`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only public documentation is [`TWizardForm` reference](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptclasses&anchor=TWizardForm). It lists names of all controls. But in a rather random order.

I find it way easier to check [`Wizard.dfm` in Inno Setup source code repository](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/main/Projects/Wizard.dfm). It defines the controls in their hierarchy. So if you [search for `InstallingPage`](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/is-6_2_1/Projects/Wizard.dfm#L625-L660), you will find that there are these controls:

```pascal
object FInstallingPage: TNewNotebookPage
  object FFilenameLabel: TNewStaticText
    ...
  end
  object FStatusLabel: TNewStaticText
    ...
  end
  object FProgressGauge: TNewProgressBar
    ...
  end
end
```

For a use in Pascal Script, drop the `F` prefix (e.g. instead of `FFilenameLabel`, use `FilenameLabel`).

Comment: Excellent! This is just what I was after. The answer to the second half of my question is `WizardForm.FilenameLabel` then. Thanks Martin.