# Inno Setup: How to shrink or resize the progress bar so that 100% label fits

Tags: inno-setup

My question is simple, how to shrink the progress bar so that 100% label fits? Otherwise I could not show in the screenshot. When it reaches 100%, it overlaps the boundary (don't know whats its called).

[image: https://i.imgur.com/8ofqnwH.jpg]

I'm using [TLama's code "percent, elapsed time and estimated time progress"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20092779).

[image]

I managed to re-arrange the labels using coordinates from enhanced edition.

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/F44LuJB.jpg]

Currently using Inno Setup 5.5.9(u)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `WizardForm.ProgressGauge` to access the progress bar:

```pascal
WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Width := WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Width - ScaleX(32);
```

See also [Inno Setup built-in control names](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45081063/850848).