# Add additional controls to standard Inno Setup pages?

Tags: checkbox, inno-setup, pascalscript

How to add checkbox to the folder selection dialog created by the Inno Setup which is shown below in the image?

[image]

This is not a custom dialog. It is created by the Inno Setup automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the `Parent` property of the checkbox to the `WizardForm.SelectDirPage`:

```pascal
var
  Checkbox: TNewCheckBox;

procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  Checkbox := TNewCheckBox.Create(WizardForm.SelectDirPage);
  Checkbox.Parent := WizardForm.SelectDirPage;
  Checkbox.Top := WizardForm.DirEdit.Top + WizardForm.DirEdit.Height + ScaleY(8);
  Checkbox.Left := WizardForm.DirEdit.Left;
  Checkbox.Caption := 'My checkbox';
  // See https://stackoverflow.com/q/30469660/850848
  Checkbox.Height := ScaleY(Checkbox.Height);
end;
```

[image]

---

For finding the page names, see:
[Inno Setup built-in control names](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45081063/850848)

For placing controls on a custom page, see:
[Placing image/control on Inno Setup custom page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43696537/850848)