# Inno installer + GI - How to move some components and other effects

Tags: inno-setup

I use Inno installer with Graphical Installer. I don't know if you have experience with it. But I would like to know how to move the components see picture. Moving the other texts around, I have solved, but I am interested in the frame where the text, the directory path and on the next page the progress bar. Is it possible to move that frame fig.1. I think it will be a GI component and I don't know its name. Primarily I want to put the directory path in a different place fig 2.

Among other things, I'm wondering if any effects can be applied. Animation (gif), video, different effects at startup etc. If there isn't a thread for that.

Example installer:

[image]

Change the position of the text and path frame. Graphical effects at startup.

Comment: I do not have any experience with GI. But in original Inno Setup, the directory edit control is `DirEdit`. See also [Inno Setup built-in control names](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45081063/850848).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Graphical Installer is based on the same Inno Setup components.

That edit box on Directory page is called **DirEdit** and you can set its position by adjusting its *Left* and *Top* properties.

Frame is actually an InnerNotebook (page of TNewNotebook component) and you can update its position the same way, e.g. in procedure InitializeWizard():

```
procedure InitializeWizard();
begin    
    #ifdef GRAPHICAL_INSTALLER_PROJECT
    // Initialize Graphical Installer skinning mechanism
    InitGraphicalInstaller();
    #endif

    // Change position of the Frame
    WizardForm.InnerNotebook.Left := 0; 
    WizardForm.InnerNotebook.Top := 0;
end;
```

Note: Changing this Frame position may broke the image shown in installer (you need to regenerate it witch changed coordinates).